# Occurrences of the sums of two dies

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 13

int main(){

    int die1, die2, sum, i, occurrences[SIZE], j=2;

    for(i=0; i<36000; i++){

        die1=1+rand()%6;
        die2=1+rand()%6;

        sum=die1+die2;

        ++occurrences[sum];
    }

    printf("%10s","Sums");

    for(i=1; i<=12; i++){
        printf("%4d", i);
    }

    printf("\n%10s","Occurrences");

    for(i=2; i<=12; i++){
        ("%4d",occurrences[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this code work? The program has to sum all the random numbers generated by two dies and then it has to print the occurrences of the sums. Why doesn't it work? The output is this:

```
          Sums   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
Occurrences
```

Comment: You're missing `printf` in the loop I guess?

Comment: Why are you printing `1` for `Sums` while not printing (trying to print) `occurrences[1]`?

Comment: `("%4d",occurrences[i]);` --> `printf("%4d",occurrences[i]);` , also, call `srand()` at the very begin if you don't want to get always the same sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The array `occurrences[SIZE]` is not initialized and has indeterminate values, so the addition `++occurrences[sum];` will invoke *undefined behavior*. You should initialize it like `occurrences[SIZE] = {0}`.
- The line `("%4d",occurrences[i]);` is just a expression using comma operator surrounded by parenthesis, so it won't do printing. It looks like `printf` should be added before the parenthesis.

Comment: I've modified the program and now it works but it doesn't show the occurrences of 12

Comment: @user10198594 Try flushing the output buffer by adding `fflush(stdout);` just before `return 0;`. By the way, are you sure what doesn't show is the occurrences of 12, not occurrences of 1?